# Copying Data from a worksheet to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

[How to Copy data from one excel file to another file in different folder using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921633/how-to-copy-data-from-one-excel-file-to-another-file-in-different-folder-using-v)

From the above link I got the codes that I was looking for.
My Query hasn't been solved yet.

I made few changes to the code to my requirements and still I get wrong results.
Below mentioned is the code that I used.

```
Sub TransferDataV2() 'transfer stuff from this workbook to workbook 2
    Dim strPath2 As String
    Dim wbkWorkbook1 As Workbook
    Dim wbkWorkbook2 As Workbook

    'define paths and filenames
    strPath2 = "E:\Purchase Register 2015-16.xlsx"

    'open files
    Set wbkWorkbook1 = ThisWorkbook '### changed this
    Set wbkWorkbook2 = Workbooks.Open(strPath2)

    'copy the values across
    '### change the sheet and range to what you need
    wbkWorkbook1.Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
    wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial

    'close the workbook
    wbkWorkbook2.Close (True)
End Sub
```

Now whenever I update some data in this workbook and try to save to another workbook, the copied data replaces the already available data in the `strPath2 = "C:\put in this.xlsx"`.
The result I require is the copied data must be saved in the `put in this.xlsx` 
but at the end of the table. Instead This code copies the data and saves them in from `A2:G5`. Kinldy Advice

Answer (score 0):

After `Selection.Copy` try:

> ```
> wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Row + 1, 1).PasteSpecial
>
> 'close the workbook
> wbkWorkbook2.Close (True)
> ```